# Why does asyncio.wait_for() need a timeout?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Below is a simple asyncio loop that runs two background tasks.

They both perform a simple count. The first one counts forever, wrapped in a 
try/except. The second one counts up to 5, then cancels the first one and 
stops the loop.

There are two ways of ensuring that the cancellation is complete -

```
asyncio.wait([a sequence of futures])

asyncio.wait_for(a single future)
```

Both take an optional timeout.

If I use the first method without a timeout, the cancellation completes and 
the loop stops.

If I use the second method without a timeout, the future is cancelled, but 
the program hangs.

If I add a timeout to the second one, it behaves the same as the first one.

Is there a reason for this?

I am using version 3.6.0.

```
import asyncio
from itertools import count

async def counter1():
    cnt = count(1)
    try:
        while True:
            print('From 1:', next(cnt))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('counter1 cancelled')

async def counter2():
    cnt = count(1)
    for i in range(5):
        print('From 2:', next(cnt))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    cnt1.cancel()
#   await asyncio.wait([cnt1])  # works
#   await asyncio.wait_for(cnt1)  # hangs
    await asyncio.wait_for(cnt1, 1)  # works
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
cnt1 = asyncio.ensure_future(counter1())
cnt2 = asyncio.ensure_future(counter2())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: I have figured out half of the answer. 'timeout' is an optional argument when using wait(), but a required one when using wait_for(). Therefore asyncio is raising an exception. However, I do not understand why no traceback appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the following answer on comp.lang.python -

"The unhandled exception is shown as a warning when the loop exits. It can't be shown prior to that because there could be some other task, even one that hasn't been scheduled yet, that might try to get the result of the counter2 task and handle the exception."

I was testing on Windows. I have never got Ctrl-C to work on Windows, so I use Ctrl-Pause, which crashes the interpreter without showing any pending tracebacks.

Running the program on Linux and pressing Ctrl-C does show the traceback. If I had been testing on Linux in the first place, there would have been no need to post the original question.